# Syntax error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: c#, asp.net

I received this server error and I can't figure out where the trouble is:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near '='.

My Code is here :

```
 public partial class v2_kradescription : System.Web.UI.Page
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
        // icnoA for appraisee icno


        string role = "";

        string kr_icno = (string)(Session["s_icno"]);
        string kr_position = (string)(Session["kr_position"]);
        string kr_description = (string)(Session["kr_description"]);

        Session["role"] = role;

        if (role == "KRA")
        {
            kr_icno = (string)(Session["s_icno"]);
            kr_position = (string)(Session["kr_position"]);
            kr_description = (string)(Session["kr_description"]);
        }
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT kr_id, kr_position, kr_description FROM tblKRAObjectiveWHERE kr_icno = " + s_icno; 
            conn.Close();
        }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message; //" Error while saving the record.";  
    }
    //conn.Open();
    //string icno = (string)(Session["s_icno"]);
    //SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT kr_id, kr_position, kr_description FROM tblKRAObjective WHERE kr_icno = " + icno;

    //conn.Close();

   }

 protected void  GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    string kr_id = Request.QueryString["kr_id"];

    string id = "";

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
    }
    Label lblposition = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblposition");
    Label lbldescription = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbldescription");

    if(e.Row.DataItem != null)
    {
        conn.Open();

        String queryA = "SELECT kr_id, kr_position, kr_description FROM tblKRAObjective  WHERE kr_icno = " + s_icno;
        SqlCommand cmdA = new SqlCommand(queryA, conn);
        SqlDataReader drA = cmdA.ExecuteReader();

        if (drA.Read())
        {
            lblposition.Text = drA["kr_position"].ToString();
            lbldescription.Text = drA["kr_description"].ToString();
        }
        drA.Close();
    }
}

 protected void GridView1_OnRowEdited(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}

     protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Focus();
}

protected void GridView1_OnRowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("kra_description.aspx?Sucess");
}

protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}

protected void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Response.Redirect("kra_pdf.aspx");
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        string kricno = (string)(Session["s_icno"]);
        string krid = (string)(Session["kr_id"]);
        string krdescription = (string)(Session["kr_description"]);
        string krposition = (string)(Session["kr_position"]); ;

        try
        {

            // get requester name, companyid, primary appraiser of requester

            String queryA = "SELECT kr_id, kr_description, kr_position FROM tblKRAObjective WHERE s_icno = '"+kricno;
            SqlCommand cmdA = new SqlCommand(queryA);
            SqlDataReader drA = cmdA.ExecuteReader();

            if (drA.Read())
            {
                krid = drA["kr_id"].ToString();
                kricno = drA["kr_icno"].ToString();
                krdescription = drA["kr_description"].ToString();
                krposition = drA["kr_position"].ToString();
            }
            drA.Close();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@kr_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = krid.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@kr_descpription", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = krdescription.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@kr_position", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = krposition.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@kr_icno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = kricno.ToString();

            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


             }
                catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = ex.Message; //" Error while saving the record.";  
        }
        Response.Redirect("kra_dashboard.aspx");
    }
}


protected void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is: `s_icno` is null or empty.

Comment: Really? You need our help to spot that you've run your table name and the `WHERE` keyword together?

Comment: Don't concatenate Strings in Queries ! Use `SqlParameter`s instead.

Comment: LOL, @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right! :-D
Add a space between "tblKRAObjective" and "WHERE" :-P

Comment: _"I can't figure out where the trouble is"_ - that's because you catch the exception and print only the message.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Easy on her, she is still a student, We were all students once and did such mistakes.

Comment: Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line you are missing a space between the table name and the `Where`

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT kr_id, kr_position, kr_description FROM tblKRAObjectiveWHERE kr_icno = " + s_icno;
```

Try this:

```
"SELECT kr_id, kr_position, kr_description FROM tblKRAObjective WHERE kr_icno = '" + s_icno + "'";
```

And in order to avoid [Sql Injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) use [Parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Do not encourage to cancatenate SQL queries!

Comment: @PawełDyl - I don't. Sometimes one just has to be patient enough until editing is finished

Comment: Ok thanks. I already fixed the problem. but now I got another error -- > The multi-part identifier "System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField" could not be bound.

Comment: This is a different question not related to your sql error that you have. Please try and debug it, read online about that error and if after all research, if it still happens, you can post another question

Comment: @fadilla'atyka  Always set a break point and debug your code when there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Please give space before Where and also add single quote to your parameter as it is string

Try Below

```
"SELECT kr_id, kr_position, kr_description FROM tblKRAObjective WHERE kr_icno = '" + s_icno + "'";
```